# Refrescar pagina al cambiar de tamaño

Tags: javascript, html

Buen día tengo mi siguiente script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).resize( function() {
window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
});
</script>
```

Con este script, al mximizar y minimizar se actualiza la pagina.
Lo cual no hay ningún problema, claro hablando desde un equipo de escritorio o laptop, la cuestión es que cuando veo la pagina desde un smartphone, la pagina se actualiza al momento de ir bajando para ver la información lo cual no es correcto, pues no debería actualizarse. Espero me puedan ayudar como podría mejorar mi script.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta guardar el ancho y si no cambia refresca la página.

```
var ancho = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() == ancho)            
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
```